# Is there a general approach to solving trigonometric equations?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

We've been solving equations in school that mainly include forms of sin, cos and tan but usually I don't know how to approach them. It's not like solving a quadratic where there's just a solution formula.

Comment: If the equation consists of finitely many sums, subtractions, multiplication, and divisions, of sines and cosines of rational multiples of an unknown $x$, there is a way to transform them into polynomial equations. The degree can be large, though, to be finding the solutions by hands this way.

Comment: I would say that there are certain classes of trigonometric equations for which the solution is known and you need to learn it. (E.g. $A\cos x+B\sin x=C$ for given $A,B,C\in\mathbb R$.) For the rest, what I've seen is that the equation often simplifies a lot if you know the basic trigonometric formulae, and by doing a lot of equations you start getting a "feeling" what can be simplified and what cannot. Sometimes still you may need an inventive step which is hard to think of. So - bottom line: a few known recipes and a lot of practice goes a long way.

Comment: Are you referring to "trigonometric identities."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [user85667](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1085900/user85667) remarks, if the equation only involves trig functions of some variable $x$ (or possibly its integer multiples), then the equation is in principle equivalent to a polynomial equation. However writing this equation down and solving it may be a very non-trivial task.

If the equation only involves $\sin$, $\cos$, and $\tan$, all of them of a *single* argument $x$, you should look for a way to express everything in terms of just **one** of these. For example, we have
$$
\sin x = \pm\frac{\tan x}{\sqrt{1+ \tan^2 x}}, ~~ \cos x = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \tan^2 x}},
$$
so this would enable you to express everything in terms of $\tan x$, and then solve for the new variable $u = \tan x$.

However this means you may end up with a lot of square roots. Another way (taking a cue from the book *Integration* by R.P. Gillespie, p. 23 in the sixth edition) is to take $u=\tan \frac{x}{2}$ instead, because we then have
$$
\sin x = \frac{2u}{1+u^2}, ~~ \cos x = \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}, ~~\tan x = \frac{2u}{1-u^2}.
$$
This will get you a *polynomial* equation in $u=\tan\frac{x}{2}$, which may or may not be easily solvable. Depending on cases, there may be a more clever substitution available.

Comment: Rational multiples of $x$ too, since you can always substitute $x=mt$, for an $m\in\mathbb{N}$ that clears all denominators.

Comment: @user85667 That's right.

Comment: Use symbol-manipulation software.  In the future all hard such questions will be solved using it... so why not start learning how to do it.

Comment: My edit was to insert the $\pm$ into the expression for $\sin$ in terms of $\tan.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Ah, thank you, you are right of course.

Comment: My own answers should not be read within 15 minutes of posting, when I am still fixing my infinite sequence of typos.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: that' s not ..yet .. a good didactical suggestion ! I am worried about whom is going to control the computers ..

Comment: "control the computers"?????   Huh?  Explain.

Answer (score 0):

It's very useful to know Euler's Formula

$$e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin\theta$$

From this (and its conjugate $e^{-i\theta} = \cos \theta - i \sin\theta$), you can derive the identities:

$$\cos\theta = \frac{e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{2}$$
$$\sin\theta = \frac{e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$$

And from these, you can derive pretty much any trig identity that you need.  For example, have you forgotten what $\sin\alpha\sin\beta$ is equivalent to?  Then just do

$$\sin\alpha\sin\beta = (\frac{e^{i\alpha} - e^{-i\alpha}}{2i})(\frac{e^{i\beta} - e^{-i\beta}}{2i})$$
$$= \frac{(e^{i\alpha} - e^{-i\alpha})(e^{i\beta} - e^{-i\beta})}{-4}$$
$$= \frac{e^{i\alpha}e^{i\beta} - e^{i\alpha}e^{-i\beta} - e^{-i\alpha}e^{i\beta} + e^{-i\alpha}e^{-i\beta}}{-4}$$
$$= \frac{e^{i(\alpha + \beta)} - e^{i(\alpha - \beta)} - e^{i(\beta-\alpha)} + e^{-i(\alpha + \beta)}}{-4}$$
$$= \frac{e^{i(\alpha + \beta)}+ e^{-i(\alpha + \beta)} - e^{i(\alpha - \beta)} - e^{-i(\alpha-\beta)} }{-4}$$
$$= \frac{2\cos(\alpha+\beta) - 2\cos(\alpha-\beta)}{-4}$$
$$= \frac{\cos(\alpha-\beta) - \cos(\alpha+\beta)}{2}$$